# Извлечение autogererated-ключа используя PreparedStatement или JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Пожалуйста, объясните как можно используя каждый из этих способов извлекать ключ.

**К примеру есть:**

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE)
public class Developer {
    String name;
    String specialty;
    Integer experience;
}
public interface DeveloperDao {
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource);

    public void createDeveloper(String name, String specialty, Integer experience);

    public List listDevelopers();

    public void removeDeveloper(String name);

    public void updateDeveloper(String name, String specialty, Integer experience);
}

@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE)
public class JdbcTemplateDeveloperDaoImpl implements DeveloperDao  {
    DataSource dataSource;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void createDeveloper(String name, String specialty, Integer experience) {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO DEVELOPERS (name, specialty, experience) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL,  name, specialty, experience);
        System.out.println("Developer successfully created.\nName: " + name + ";\nSpecilaty: " +
                specialty + ";\nExperience: " + experience + "\n");

    }



    @Override
    public List listDevelopers() {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM DEVELOPERS";
        List developers = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new DeveloperMapper());
        return developers;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeDeveloper(String name) {
        String SQL = "DELETE FROM DEVELOPERS WHERE name = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, name);
        System.out.println("Developer with id: " + name + " successfully removed");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDeveloper(String name, String specialty, Integer experience) {
        String SQL = "UPDATE DEVELOPERS SET name = ?, specialty = ?, experience = ? ";
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, name, specialty, experience);
        System.out.println("Developer with id: " + name + " successfully updated.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете получить ключи если передадите параметер объекта класса [`GeneratedKeyHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html) в `jdbcTemplate` метод.

В случае [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) вы можете использовать константу [`RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) в качестве второго параметра

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,
                                  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```